# Add one character from a string to the end of another string (strcat)

Tags: c, c-strings, strcat

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++) {
  if (s[i] != ' ') 
    strcat(p, s[i]);
```

I want to add the current character of the `s` string at the end of the `p` string provided it is not a space. How do I do that using `strcat`? The code above gives the following error "invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*'".

I want to use `strcat` because this way I don't have to store an index for p string in order to know where to place the current character. I hope this makes sense.

Also, I need to do this using array of chars, not c-strings or whatever those are called.

Comment: [`strncat`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncat) might work for you: `strncat(p, &s[i], 1);`.

Comment: That worked, thanks a lot.

Comment: Note that the use of `strlen()` in the loop like that requires the code to evaluate the length on each iteration.  It would be *much* more sensible to know how long the string currently is so you can add the extra characters without having to call `strcat()` — which also has to scan the string on each iteration.  You have quadratic code — O(N²) — because of the function calls, but the underlying algorithm only needs to be linear — O(N).

Comment: Note too that both `p` and `s` must be C strings — that is, a null-terminated byte sequence — because neither `strlen()` nor `strcat()` will work sanely if they're not strings.  So your last comment is misguided.

Comment: *"How do I do that using strcat?"* - you don't; you use a simple reader-writer loop that reads from your source buffer and conditionally writes to your  target, terminating when you're done. Don't pound nails with saws.

Comment: You must also first ensure that the storage allocated for p is large enough to append all of the extra characters without overrunning that space.

Answer (score 4):

A more sensible algorithm would avoid using `strcat()` or `strncat()` altogether:

```
int j = strlen(p);
for (int i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
    if (s[i] != ' ')
        p[j++] = s[i];
}
p[j] = '\0';
```

This avoids quadratic behaviour which using `strlen()` and `strcat()` (or `strncat()`) necessarily involves.  It does mean you need to keep a track of where to place characters in `p`, but the work involved in doing that is trivial.  Generally speaking, the quadratic behaviour won't be a problem on strings of 10 characters or so, but if the strings reach 1000 bytes or more, then quadratic behaviour becomes a problem (it takes 1,000,000 operations instead of 1,000 operations — that can become noticeable).

Comment: I was never told about how these function works at a low level. I am preparing for a college exam next year and this kind of things are not taught in high school. Until then I just want to get good at problem solving, being able to get the idea behind it, not so much the effectiveness of the implementation. That's why I prefer the strcat, I don't need to keep another variable to keep count of the index of the second string. Thanks for your insight, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need addresses (the array itself is an address to the first element) to pass to the `strcat`, not a `char`. That is why you need to use the `&` operator before s[i].

You have a working example here

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{

    char s[50]= "Hello World";
    char p[50]= "Hello World";
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<strlen(s);i++){
    if(s[i]!=' ') 
    strncat(p,&s[i],1);
    }
    puts(p);
    return 0;
}
```